# Draggable popup in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm using a PopupPanel but by default it cannot be dragged on the screen. Is the way to make id draggable or I should use whole another component?

Comment: FYI, `DialogBox` is draggable (by the title bar)

Comment: thans, why don't you make it as an answer so I could accept it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DialogBox` class is draggable, by its title bar (which a `PopupPanel` doesn't have; also note that `DialogBox` extends `DecoratedPopupPanel`, not just `PopupPanel`, and sizing works differently than for `PopupPanel`).